# C# NotifyIcon ShowBalloonTip timeout

Tags: c#, notifyicon, balloon

In my c# (2.0 framework) application I'm using notify Icon control.
I want to show from this control a balloon tip. but the "showBalloonTip" event i slimite to a timeout and I want to show this balloon forever. I've tried to use a timer that will show the balloon again and again but in vista there is a fading effect for balloons and if it is not disabled every 25-30 seconds the balloon will fade in.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The balloon is faded by default and it's part of the Windows common behavior. You can't adjust it. What you could do is create a form, place is manually next to the toolbar region and display it topmost (but non-dialog) and use the BalloonTipShown event to override the display of the actual balloon.